# If-else conditional assignment in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ternary-operator

I want to assign values to a column depending on the values of an already-existing column. This code works, but I would like to do it not-in-place, perhaps using `assign` or `apply`.

If this could be done in one step it would also avoid the implicit conversion from `int` to `float` that occurs below.

I've included my attempt using `assign`, which raises a `ValueError`.

```
import pandas as pd

original = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

d = original.copy()
d.loc[d.col.isin(['b', 'x']), 'new'] = 1
d.loc[~d.col.isin(['b', 'x']), 'new'] = 99
d

# :   col   new
# : 0   a  99.0
# : 1   b   1.0
# : 2   c  99.0

# original.assign(new=lambda x: (1 if x.col.isin(['b', 'x']) else 99)) # ValueError
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where()`:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
original["new"] = np.where(original["col"].isin(["b", "x"]), 1, 99)
print(original)
#  col  new
#0   a   99
#1   b    1
#2   c   99
```

Comment: `original.assign(new=lambda x: np.where(x["col"].isin(["b", "x"]), 1, 99))` is just what I wanted. Thanks.